# Want to remove global_name from DB links (Oracle 11g)

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, functions, remote, dblink

I am trying to call remote function via `DB LINKS`.

However, My global name contains the string `ON` and I believe it causes an error.

The Error I have is ...

```
SQL> var tmp varchar2(2);
SQL> execute :tmp := IF_TRX_SKY.CREATEWITH@SKYLBS_LINK2.I-ON.NET('a', 1, 2, 't', 't', 'k', 'm', 'r', 'u', 's', 's', 't', 'k', '00', sysdate, 1);
BEGIN :tmp := IF_TRX_SKY.CREATEWITH@SKYLBS_LINK2.I-ON.NET('a', 1, 2, 't', 't', 'k', 'm', 'r', 'u', 's', 's', 't', 'k', '00', sysdate, 1); END;

                                                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 52:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ON" when expecting one of the following:
( - + case mod new null <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
continue avg count current max min prior sql stddev sum
variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval date
<a string literal with character set specification>
<a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
<an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
<an alternatively-quoted SQ
```

I assume that if I removed `.I-ON.NET` part, it would work.

How can I remove/escape this? Oracle documentation states that `GLOBAL_NAME` is required for replication. Then how can I call this remote function without removing the `GLOBAL_NAME`?

Here is my create statement to create `DB LINKS`

```
SQL> CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK SKYLBS_LINK2                     
  2  CONNECT TO ICE
  3  IDENTIFIED BY ICE1234
  4  USING 'ORCL';

Database link created.
```

And this is setting what I have

```
NAME                             TYPE        VALUE                 
---------------------------- ----------- ----------------
global_names                    boolean      FALSE
```

FYI, I can not change config files or reboot database, since I don't have permissions.

Summary:

- How to remove `GLOBAL_NAME` from `DB LINKS` which I never write in my create statement.
- How to execute remote function which contains a forbidden string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove DB_DOMAIN from DB_LINKS.

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET global_names = false SCOPE = SPFILE;
ALTER SYSTEM SET db_domain = '' SCOPE = SPFILE;
UPDATE GLOBAL_NAME SET GLOBAL_NAME = [Name without db_domain];
```

then restart, DB and Listener.

However, I still do not know how to use this with domain.